# Trying to get the date as a string from a Calendar object

Tags: android

I found the following code (from stack overflow) to get the date as a string:

```
String test=c.getDisplayName(DAY, SHORT, Locale.US);
```

right now it says `DAY, SHORT Local.US` is undefined.  I also tried;

```
String test=c.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY, Calendar.SHORT, Calendar.Locale.US);
```

It still did not work.

Comment: Are you trying to get the day or the date as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
String test=c.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY, Calendar.SHORT, java.util.Locale.getDefault());
```